# How to split single column data into multiple columns in ssrs reports?

Tags: reporting-services, split

I have one table as shown in bellow

EmpID    Name
1        Ram,Shaker,Sarath
2        Raju,Ravi

[image]

I need output as

EmpID   Name   Name
1       Ram    Shaker,Sarath
2       Raju   Ravi

Comment: Instead of doing from SSRS report, why don't you make SQL query like your expected output!

Answer (score 1):

For the first column, you can use the Split function and take the first element:

```
=IIf(
  Split(Fields!myColumn.Value, ",").Length > 1,
  Split(Fields!myColumn.Value, ",").GetValue(0),
  Fields!myColumn.Value
)
```

For the second column, you can use the Right function to grab the remaining characters:

```
=IIf(
  Split(Fields!myColumn.Value, ",").Length > 1,
  Right(
    Fields!myColumn.Value,
    LEN(Fields!myColumn.Value) - LEN(Split(Fields!myColumn.Value, ",").GetValue(0)) - 1
  ),
  ""
)
```

The `LEN()` function is for BIDS.  Use `LENGTH()` instead if you're in Report Builder.

Comment: Thank you all:   in-case i have around 20 name separated by comma with respect to EmpID=10
i need to 10 names in one column and another 10 in another column
how it possible

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from @pedram, but assuming you go down the path of a report, I would be using the InStr function with the Left Function

so you have something like the following function in a column/cell of a table

```
=Left(Name, InStr(Name, ","))
```

The InStr  function finds the first instance of the comma and reports is position to the Left function

Now this assumes that the the comma is the delimiter.